# How to use PHP interact with YouTube API?

Tags: php, api, video, upload, youtube

I want to let my website's user to upload their video to **YouTube**, but is through my youtube account.That is, all the video uploaded will store in my YouTube account.

I've used the `ClientLogin` method

```
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php#ClientLogin_for_Installed_Applications
```

But the docs said that the method is deprecated, and recommend me to use OAuth2.0
But I can't find a method that likes ClientLogin in here

```
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol?hl=zh-TW#Authentication
```

So.. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you read the page you gave a link to? There is a plenty of information about how authentication should be done with OAuth2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!!!!!!!

Answer is use ServiceAccount,
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount